# SQL query to fetch based on the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to read data from `parent and child_address`.But child_address is not having parent_id.`Query1 and Query2` are working fine.If I combine error is coming.Data in child and other tables are optional, only parent will have the data so I am using left join.Please help me to solve this.

**Tables:**

```
create table parent(p_id number,name varchar(5));
create table table1(t1_id number,p_id number,t1_name varchar(5));
create table table2(t2_id number,p_id number,t2_name varchar(5));

create table child(c_id number,p_id number,c_name varchar(5));
create table child_address(ca_id number,c_id number,city varchar(5));
```

**Fields Required:**

```
parent.name,table1.name,table2.name,child_address.city
```

**Query1:**

```
select parent.p_id,table1.t1_name,table2.t2_name from parent
left join table1 on parent.p_id = table1.p_id
left join table2 on parent.p_id = table2.p_id;
```

**Query2:**

```
select child.p_id,child.c_id,child_address.ca_id,child_address.city from child
left join child_address on child.c_id = child_address.c_id;
```

**Combined Query:**

```
select a.*,b.* from (
select * from (
select parent.p_id,table1.t1_name,table2.t2_name from parent
left join table1 on parent.p_id = table1.p_id
left join table2 on parent.p_id = table2.p_id) as a
left join 
select * from (
select child.p_id,child.c_id,child_address.ca_id,child_address.city from child
left join child_address on child.c_id = child_address.c_id) as b  on a.pid = b.pid)
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for reply, ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle? These are two different DBMS.

Comment: Thanks for reply,SQL Server or general rule to follow also good to have.

Answer (score 1):

```
select    
  p.name, t1.t1_name, t2.t2_name, ca.city 
from   
  parent p   
  left join table1 t1 on t1.p_id = p.p_id   
  left join table2 t2 on t2.p_id = p.p_id   
  left join child  c  on c.p_id  = p.p_id   
  left join child_address ca on ca.c_id = c.c_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there ay rule is there to follow? could you give me such link or something?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @sunleo: A rule? Well, you say that you want to select from parent and other tables, but those other tables are optional. So you left-outer-join them. If you want to group this into two subqueries for parent and child you can do so (your approach / my answer), but it is not necessary. The only rule for directly outer-joining: If you join something to an outer-joined table, this must also be an outer join (i.e. even if every child had an address, you would have to outer join the child addresses too when outer-joining child).

Answer (score 1):

1.`pid` instead of `p_id` on the subquery.

2.Try to remove `AS` keywrod after `FROM` and `JOIN` subquery as below

You can try.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    a.name,
                    a.t1_name,
                    a.t2_name,
                    b.city
          FROM      ( SELECT    parent.p_id ,
                                parent.name,
                                table1.t1_name,
                                table2.t2_name
                      FROM      parent
                                LEFT JOIN table1 ON parent.p_id = table1.p_id
                                LEFT JOIN table2 ON parent.p_id = table2.p_id
                    ) a
                    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  child.p_id ,
                                        child.c_id ,
                                        child_address.ca_id ,
                                        child_address.city
                                FROM    child
                                        LEFT JOIN child_address ON child.c_id = child_address.c_id
                              )  b ON a.p_id = b.p_id
        )  a1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44daf/48)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an opening parenthesis here: `left join select * from`. It must be: `left join (select * from`  instead.

Anyway, you have made your query a bit too complicated. `(select * from (<query>))` can be written as `(<query>)`. So this should simply be:

```
select * from (<parent query>) p left outer join (<child query>) c on c.p_id = p.p_id;
```

Of course you can do the same with `WITH` clauses:

```
with p as (<parent query>), 
     c as (<child query>)
select * from p left join c on c.p_id = p.p_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.